# How to add some known objects to ace editors syntax checker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

we're using the ACE editor to write javascript code that's interpreted on the server side. So the server has a JavaScript interface and can execute submitted code to accomplish some task from the outside.

The server implements some new objects that are not known by ACE. So ACE shows a warning, if one of this unknown objects is used in code.

What is the correct way to tell ACE, that there are some new objects, variables und functions? I already took a look into worker-javascript.js, but I DON'T want to reimplement this whole stuff (updating ACE would get harder than). Is there any interface I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ace uses jshint, which have an option to set a list of global variables.
Ace supports changeOptions call on worker to modify default options it passes to jshint, but doesn't have a way to pass list of gloabals

You can add it by changing line at https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.1.8/lib/ace/mode/javascript_worker.js#L130
to `lint(value, this.options, this.options.globals);`

and from your code calling

```
editor.session.$worker.call("changeOptions", [{
   globals: {foo: false, bar: false...},
   undef: true, // enable warnings on undefined variables
   // other jshint options go here check jshint site for more info
}]);
```

the change to worker.js#L130 is simple enough and should be accepted if you make a pull request to ace

Comment: That seems to work. Can you please add a short explaination of how it works and what "undef: true" is doing? Do you know the options that I can use in the globals object?

Comment: updated, see https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/src/options.js for the full list of jshint options

Comment: You may need to set a timeout (or other method) to delay the call above until the editor is done being setup by ace or you will get an error due to the worker not "existing" yet.